# pywinauto - how to control MFCReportCtrl?

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

My window application has MFCReportCtrl control as the list of input fields.  But I can't detect child controls in MFCReportCtrl.  print_control_identifiers() only shows following

```
MFCReportCtrl - 'Connection List'    (L710, T406, R1169, B543)
 | ['Connection List', 'MFCReportCtrl', 'Connection ListMFCReportCtrl', 'Connection List0', 'Connection List1', 'MFCReportCtrl0', 'MFCReportCtrl1', 'Connection ListMFCReportCtrl0', 'Connection ListMFCReportCtrl1']
 | child_window(title="Connection List", class_name="MFCReportCtrl")
 |    |
 |    | Header - ''    (L712, T408, R1167, B425)
 |    | ['HeaderSession Data', 'Header', 'Session InformationHeader', 'Session InformationHeader0', 'Session InformationHeader1', 'Header0', 'Header1']
 |    | child_window(class_name="SysHeader32")
```

When I tried to print controls of "SysHeader32", I've got nothing.

I think it is because MFCReportCtrl is not standard window control, but I need a way to control it because most of input fields on my application are child of MFCReportCtrl.  It would be grateful if anyone can give advice.

Thanks in advance your help!

- Added screenshot of SAWPY

[image]

- Screenshot of Inspector.exe

[image]

- Screenshot of Spy++

[image]

Comment: What shows Inspect.exe?

Comment: I'm using SWAPY and it shows only "Connect List" without any child controls.

Comment: SWAPY is not maintained. It supports only old win32 backend. Read about Spy tools for every backend here: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Comment: I've got the same tree of elements with Spy++ and inspector.

Comment: Oh, bad news. This is custom control. But if its source code is available, it may be possible to implement custom wrapper for it.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov, did you mean that I need to change source code for it? or I can make custom wrapper by using source code?

Comment: It depends how the source code is implemented. If window message handlers are already there, it's enough to implement Python wrapper only. Otherwise both sides should be changed.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov, oh my god..  do you happen to know any tutorial or examples of making custom wrapper with message handlers?

Comment: All we have is existing wrappers for standard controls: [win32_controls.py#L283](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/pywinauto/controls/win32_controls.py#L283). Is this control source code available as open source?